# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo and its brothers works on SQL2000?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2000, smo

As title, I need that to run an import script generated by SQL Server DB Publishing Tool. Would that work on Sql2000 server too? Also I have seen ppl reporting missing library issues related to GAC, which libraries I precisely need to include if I am not controlling the deployment server?

To know how this thing works you can check here in MSDN Forum.
http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3947420&SiteID=1

I tested and indeed it works in my devbox with SQL2005 Express installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SMO works on SQL Server 2000:

[SMO and Sql Server 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457/smo-and-sql-server-70)

Answer (score 0):

[Partially](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162130(SQL.90).aspx)... so both the "yes" and "no" answers are correct