# How to find sql2000 databases info using Sqlserver SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

How to Find sqlserver2000 databases info using SQLSERVER-SMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can get some ideas from this one [SMO and Sql Server 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457/smo-and-sql-server-7-0).